# How can I force including a header, always?

Tags: c++, header, include, codeblocks

I have been working in Visual Studio on a project and had a header file which I included in every other header file using Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Forced Include File. How do I do this in Code Blocks?

Comment: Where the menu used `Advanced` it should have used `Lock-in`.

Comment: What's wrong with the good old `#include` wherever it's needed?

Comment: @Mat: I have used forced includes for two purposes: (1) anti-sillywarnings for visual c++, and (2) macros for C++11 features, while compilers were catching up (and yeah, still). The latter usage is just far more convenient and less error prone than specifying those macros in the build commands. Better to have them in a file, with all the usual header lookup machinery to provide compiler and system specific definitions. :-)

Comment: @mat Right now, the wrong thing is that I have about 120 .h files in the project, and I just thought it looked better if didn't have one more include in every file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code::Blocks uses the g++ compiler by default.

With g++ the option to force a header inclusion is `-include` *file*, which you just put in the IDE settings (e.g. right click project, select build options, IIRC).

To find that information I just googled "forced include g++", which landed me at (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), the relevant **documentation**.

It's often a good idea to consult the documentation, and if that fails, google.

Or as in this case, the opposite order, but anyway, that's a good idea.

Comment: Somehow I was stupid enough to not google for the 'forced' keyword -.- Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd use `perl` to include the header file in question, e.g., after the first header file in a given file and would run the perl script on all `.cpp` files, probably using `find`. Put differently: I would change all `.cpp` files but not manually (unless there are just a few files involved).